# Имеет ли смысл добавить статью о пользе отладки собственного кода перед созданием вопроса?

Tags: обсуждение, справка

Стал замечать что очень много новичков не знают о необходимости и/или возможности отладки своего кода, и полагаются исключительно на понимание того, что написали, вместо того чтобы запустить отладку и посмотреть результаты. Это, конечно, хороший навык, но отсутствие элементарного прогона через отладчик и проверки значений переменных намного сократил бы количество вопросов, где мы выполняли бы роль отладчиков, задавая уточняющие вопросы.

Вследствие этого спрашиваю: есть ли возможность как-либо добавить необходимость самостоятельной отладки кода перед созданием вопроса в, например, [статье по созданию самодостаточного вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Есть ли в этом так же необходимость, как считаете? Видя много новичков, приходящих и задающих вопросы впервые, как-то будет легче не совершать повторяющиеся действия и поместить ссылку на статью в Помощи, где были бы примеры отладки.

Comment: Есть вот что: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701489/218063, можно закрывать вопросы, которые решаются отладкой как дубликаты

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> есть ли возможность

Возможность есть.

> Есть ли в этом так же необходимость, как считаете?

Необходимость может и есть, но она разбивается о факт того, что новички (да и часть старичков) справку не читали и читать не будут.

Comment: А если в визарде создания вопроса добавить шаг? Справа и инструкция и блок полезных ссылок -- это как-то кастомизирутся?

Comment: @AK было б неплохо. Просто справку мы можем и сами поправить, а визерд только через MSE. В визарде только локальки можем править.

Comment: Ещё я думаю у нас когнитивное искажение может быть. Мы не знаем, сколько людей прочитало -- но каждый случай, когда не читают нам постоянно в глаза тычет из всех утюгов  и очередей проверок.

Comment: @AK не знаем, потому что SE эти метрики не снимают и A/B тестов на это не проводят. Посему, мы не можем узнать корреляцию между "плохими" вопросами и фактом того, прочитал ли этот участник справку.